# Server Error in Application "My web site"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've bougth an web hosting wervice so I can put my web site on it. But I got this problem 
Server Error in Application "my website":

```
**Detailed Error Information**
Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code  0x80070002
Requested URL   http://mywebsite.se:80/Index.cshtml?aspxerrorpath=/
Physical Path   E:\inetpub\webhosting\industri2\mywebsite.se\www\Index.cshtml
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
**Most likely causes:**
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.
```

Earlyer I got this problem `CustomErrors mode=“RemoteOnly”` but I put it on off now. And this problem comes up: `server error in application`. I'm using mvc and ms web dev 2010 have a publish and I'm using it. But got this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things to check:

1. Is the hosting provider running the correct version of ASP.Net
2. Is razor supported
3. The actual file exists on the path you set, try putting an ordinary HTML file in there to see if you can hit it

Comment: hi! i have tried to put an ordinary html file and it works. but i don't know if razor supported and running the correct asp.net version. how can i check that?

Comment: @newb eaiest option is to ask the administrator of the server.

Comment: ok i will ask the administrator of the server. and be back with the info. and thx so far.

Comment: it was the wrong asp.net version. it's fixed now. thax Hacked and Rowland